# How do you open a logfile (.rdf) downloaded from an EV3 brick?

Tags: ev3, ev3-g

I have been logging data for a few sensors, and would like to import that data into Excel. What exactly do I need to do? I remember reading somewhere that LabView can export logging data (I have the Education version) but I cannot get LabView to open the datalog files.

Comment: I couldn't find much out there.  Maybe these docs will help you more than they enlightened me: http://s3.amazonaws.com/scschoolfiles/379/data_logging.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Education software:

- Open a new experiment.
- Go to the *Tools* menu and select *Data Log File Manager*.
- Browse to the the `.rdf` file and click the *Import* button. (It can be on the brick or on your computer.)
- Close the *Data Log File Manager*
- On the *Tools* menu, select *Export Datasets*
- Save the file as a `.csv` file
- Open the `.csv` file in Excel