# How can I read NXT logfiles?

Tags: nxt

I used the logfile feature to collect light intensity values.
How can I get a view to this data? 
On the NXT brick I only found: "delete" or "send" but not "show". I tried "send" when I had an USB conection to a PC, but I couldn't find a file in the download folder. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you open a logfile (.rdf) downloaded from an EV3 brick?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/8746/how-do-you-open-a-logfile-rdf-downloaded-from-an-ev3-brick)

Comment: @chicks This might be considered a duplicate if both EV3 and NXT have identical data log structures.